Homotopy type of simplicial complexes related to the affine building of GL(n)
Let X be the affine building of $GL_{n}(F)$, where $F$ is a $p$-adic field and $n>2$. For each simplex $\sigma$ of $X$, we write $\rm{Ch}(\sigma)$ for the set of chambers $X$ containing $\sigma$.
We define a finite simplicial complex $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ whose vertices are the codimension one simplices of the chambers in $\rm{Ch}(\sigma)$. The simplices of $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ are of the form $S=\{F_0,...,F_q\}$, where $F_0,...,F_q$ are contained in the same chamber.
The simplicial complex $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ is very particular : it is of the same dimension as $X$ (ie. $\dim(\mathcal{P}_{\sigma})=\dim(X)=n-1$), and every simplex of $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ of dimension at least $1$ is
contained in a unique chamber of $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$. So two distinct chambers of $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ are disjoint or intersects along a vertex.
If $\sigma$ is a simplex of $X$ of dimension at least $n-2$ (that is $\sigma$ is a chamber or a codimension one simplex), it is easy to see that $\mathcal{P}_{\sigma}$ is a cone and then its geometric realization is contractible.
However, when $\sigma$ is a simplex of $X$ of dimension at most $n-3$ the situation is more complicated. I try to prove that if $\dim(\sigma)\leqslant n-3$ then the geometric realization is also contractible.

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yy5ffyugcvrpyaa5y4v2a/geogebra-export-33.jpg?rlkey=4cpv1zpm7ckdfbw3zt0ze72we&st=yszfvxa4&dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yy5ffyugcvrpyaa5y4v2a/geogebra-export-33.jpg?rlkey=4cpv1zpm7ckdfbw3zt0ze72we&st=yszfvxa4&dl=0
